# How to get the slope of the endpoints in a hermite spline?

Tags: graphics, spline

So the slope of a non-endpoint point P1 in a hermite curve is (P2-P0)/2. But how would you get the slope of the endpoints, if I don't want the slope to be 0?

Comment: Don't you need to supply the tangents of the endpoints to calculate a hermite spline? If you're supplying the tangents as control points, it would just be (c0.y - p0.y) / (c0.x - p0.x) for the first end point, and (c1.y - p1.y) / (c1.x - p1.x) for the second point. (Be sure to watch out for a 0 in the denominator!)

Comment: Wow, 2 days of nothing an we both respond within minutes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you mean a quadratic Bezier curve which is defined by two end points and one (inner) control point, because the Hermite curve is already defined by tangent vectors (from which the slope is simply R<sub>*i y*</sub> / R<sub>*i x*</sub>, i=0..1,  where R<sub>0</sub> and R<sub>1</sub> are the tangent vectors). Also, the Hermite curve is cubic and has 4 control points, ie. 2 inner control points.

So, for a quadratic Bezier curve, defined by P<sub>0</sub>, P<sub>1</sub>, P<sub>2</sub>, the tangents at the end=points P<sub>0</sub> and P<sub>3</sub>, are just

> T<sub>0</sub> = P<sub>1</sub> - P<sub>0</sub>
>   T<sub>1</sub> = P<sub>2</sub> - P<sub>1</sub>

So the slopes are

> s<sub>0</sub> = T<sub>0 *y*</sub> / T<sub>0 *x*</sub>
>   s<sub>1</sub> = T<sub>1 *y*</sub> / T<sub>1 *x*</sub>

That's why these curve are so amazingly useful, because they're defined by the features that we want to control for the purposes of design (continuity among segments by placing control points on a straight line through the common endpoint).

The quadratic Bezier can also be considered a *degenerate* cubic Bezier, where the 2 inner control points coincide (they are the same point); so the first step to convert the "3-point" curve into the Hermite form is to duplicate the middle point producing the cubic Bezier form.

> B<sub>0</sub> = P<sub>0</sub>
>   B<sub>1</sub> = P<sub>1</sub>
>   B<sub>2</sub> = P<sub>1</sub>
>   B<sub>3</sub> = P<sub>2</sub>

Then, using equation (13.32) from Foley and Van Dam, *Fundamentals of Interactive Computer Graphics*, the Hermite form can be produced with a matrix multiplication

```
G_h = [ [ H_0 ]   = [ [  1  0  0  0 ]   [ [ B_0 ]    = M_hb G_b
        [ H_1 ]       [  0  0  0  1 ]     [ B_1 ]
        [ T_0 ]       [ -3  3  0  0 ]     [ B_2 ]
        [ T_1 ] ]     [  0  0 -3  3 ] ]   [ B_3 ] ]
```

Ie. The two end-points are the same (H<sub>0</sub> = B<sub>0</sub>, H<sub>1</sub> = B<sub>3</sub>), and the tangent vectors are just weighted sums of the relevant points (T<sub>0</sub> = -3*B<sub>0</sub> + 3*B<sub>1</sub>, T<sub>1</sub> = -3*B<sub>2</sub> + 3*B<sub>3</sub>).

The tangent vectors here differ in magnitude from the first definitions above, but the directions (and hence, the slope) are the same.

Comment: Thanks! If Hermite curves are only defined by 4 control points, then what happens when there are only 3 specified so far? The Bezier curve seems a lot more useful in this way... what about Catmull-Rom splines? I thought they were the same as Hermite, but I guess tangent creation is specified for Hermite curves, and automatic for Catmull-Rom since there's the equation T = (P2-P0)/2. Is there a way to calculate the tangents of the endpoints in this case? Or is Bezier the only curve/spline that can do so?

Comment: *Bezier* curves are defined by points (3 for quadratic, 4 for cubic, 5 for quartic, ...); *Hermite* curves are defined by 2 endpoints and 2 tangent vectors, and can be converted into/from cubic Beziers. I'm not entirely sure about Catmull-Rom splines. The papers I have by Catmull (in Herbert Freeman, ed., *Tutorial and selected readings in Interactive Computer Graphics*, and Kellogg S. Booth, ed., *Tutorial: Computer Graphics*) all work with Beziers, so I think they're the same or easily convertible. ...

Comment: The best source for all of these (and the math to work with them) is Foley and Van Dam, *Fundamentals of Interactive Computer Graphics*.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the book out and try the curve conversions.

Comment: I've copied the relevant equation here. The results are easy to apply, but the book should help a lot for understanding. I've also relied on Bill Casselman's *Mathematical Illustrations*, which uses the PostScript language for programming examples.